# ddbt python transformation: numpy not found

Tags: python, dbt

Trying to make a simple transform layer in DBT with python isntead of sql.

this is my model:

```
def model(dbt, session):
    dbt.config(materialized="table")
    get_table = dbt.source("tap-spreadsheets-anywhere", "tracks").df()
    
    # feature calcuations goes here. 
    final_df = get_table.copy()
    final_df['feature1_test'] = 1
    return final_df
```

When i dbt run i get the error:

```
Python model failed:
No module named 'numpy'
```

strange since i did not call numpy or try to import it? Seems like I am following their footsteps:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/python-models

I would love your input on this